# Angular Bundle size issue

Tags: jss

[image: Sitecore auto created modules]

To get a better understanding of the JSS library I ran the bundle analyzer on the Angular Sample project and I'm getting 169 modules on my main bundle. Does anybody knows where those 169 modules are coming from?

The total bundle size of my sample project looks like this:

```
bundle.js (polyfills) 59.7 kB 
main.bundle.js (main) 302 kB 
styles.bundle.css (styles) 51.6 kB
inline.bundle.js (inline) 796 bytes
```

Is that normal for a startup project using JSS, even after using the --prod flags?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is purely about Angular, not about Sitecore.

Comment: I was wondering the same...the out-of-the box Angular + JSS production build is roughly TWICE the size as a hello world angular production build...and the bloat seems to be in main.ts with 169 modules, where the hello world main.ts only has ~20.

Comment: @JarmoJarvi I'm just wondering if there is a bug in the @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular library that is generating 149 extra modules, causing the main bundle to double in size.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the `ModuleConcatenationPlugin`, try commenting it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done some research and testing into this and it appears to be normal. The `webpack-bundle-analyzer` has issues with the `ModuleConcatenationPlugin`, as Alex Smagin pointed out ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer/issues/115) - note that angular-cli is not using Webpack 4)

To test, I hacked angular-cli's webpack config locally to remove the `ModuleConcatenationPlugin`. The bundle analyzer picture looks drastically different with concatenation off:

[image: no-concat bundle analysis]

Without the concatenation there is no huge-looking main.ts, because the system stuff being lumped into that is no longer there.

The bundle size with module concatenation off is about 50k larger than with it on, so the optimization is definitely doing something.

Note: I analyzed the Angular Advanced app.

Angular definitely is a pretty hefty library.

Methodology:

Angular config hacked: `advanced-sample-angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\production.js`

Command to build (modified `jss build:client-bundle`):

`cross-env-shell ng build --target=production --environment=prod --base-href / --deploy-url $npm_package_config_sitecoreDistPath/browser --output-path=$npm_package_config_buildArtifactsPath/browser --prod --stats-json`

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 8 if you set "optimization": false in angular.json, it will not concatenate. However, the bundle size will be substantially higher