# React vendor chunk size quite large

Tags: jss

I recently started working on a **JSS React** template. Today I ran `jss build` and found that the vendor chunk size is 436KB non-gzipped. Being that JSS is built on top of CRA whose vendor files total 118KB, I'm a bit worried about the ~320KB difference.

I also checked Chrome's coverage devtool and found that 43% of the vendor code is not actually used, although I assume it would be less in connected mode (I have no way to test that yet).

[image]

Now, I am aware that JSS is currently in Tech Preview, so I'm curious if this point will be addressed in the final release or if it's even seen as a concern by the dev team. At the moment, loading half a MB for just libs is a huge performance hit for our users and I'm reluctant about using JSS in production.

Am I missing something? Is there anything else I can do aside from ejecting and/or caching the files?

Thank you!

**Please note** that this is a different question than [Angular Bundle size issue](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11572/angular-bundle-size-issue?newreg=f014a23d4e5a4cd8ae8dee7132cb3a55) which concerns the unknown modules, and not the chunk size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the vendors chunk for the JSS React sample app is ~430KB before gzip (after gzip that number is ~116KB). The disparity with the "vanilla" CRA bundle size is a result of the additional dependencies that are used by the JSS sample app, e.g. Apollo for GraphQL, i18next for translation, etc...

The important thing to understand is that you are *not required* to use a JSS sample app as the basis for a production app. The sample apps are intended to be just that, samples. As such, they have to strike a balance between getting started with JSS and demonstrating the features of JSS - all of which requires pulling in dependencies you may not ultimately need in your app.

To that end, in a React app - regardless of whether or not it is based on CRA - the only dependency you need in order to use the JSS helper components in your app is `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react`. Any other dependency in the sample apps is to support the various JSS development modes and the various Sitecore/JSS features demonstrated in the sample apps.

Comment: Thanks, Adam! I dug around a bit and found that the major difference, approximately ~250KB, comes from the GraphQL and Apollo packages, not Sitecore itself. Is there any documentation for implementing the `sitecore-jss-react` module without the extra dependencies? If not, I'll try to reverse engineer the bundle and implement code splitting where possible.